# Is $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ composed of finite measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, total-variation

Let $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that vanish at infinity. By Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem, the dual of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ composed of all the real-valued regular Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. I am wondering whether all the measures in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ are finite. I think it is true since by [the definition of TV norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation), for any $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$,
$$
|\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)|\leq|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^d)=\|\mu\|_{\mathrm{TV}}<\infty.
$$
But I check the textbook, for example "a course in functional analysis" by John Conway and it seems like the "finiteness" is not mentioned. So is the above argument correct?

Comment: The measures are finite, furthermore, the measures in the dual have finite total variation, that is $|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^n)<\infty$

Comment: Check out Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Theorem 6.4 on Page 118 - every complex measure has finite total variation.  It is not trivial so I suggest read the section starting with page 116 for the definition of complex measure and existence of total variation.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks. Here I am considering real-valued continuous functions space and the measures in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are real-valued. The book you recommended is about complex-valued measure. Does real-valued or complex-valued matter for the result?

Comment: @Lin2568: Same result.  A real-valued measure is a complex-valued measure whose values are in $\Bbb{R}$.  So the result on complex-valued measure can be used.  Note that real-valued or complex-valued measures differ from positive measures which are allowed to take the value $+\infty$.

Comment: @ChadK I have a follow-up question. Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Since $m(\mathbb{R}^d)=\infty$, can I say that $m$ is not a complex measure, or not a real measure? Does it mean that $m\notin\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$? Thank you!

Comment: @Lin2568:  It's a positive measure, but it's not in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ because it would have to have $\infty$ norm, and Banach spaces are only permitted to have elements of finite norm.  Elements of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ must have finite total variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most authors take it as part of the definition of "real-valued measure" or "signed measure" that the measure should be finite, i.e. that $\mu(A)$ is a **finite** real number for each set $A$ in the $\sigma$-algebra.  Certainly that is what's intended here.

Some condition like this is needed in order for the additivity property of the measure to make sense.  If $A,B$ are two disjoint sets, we are supposed to have $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$, but if we had $\mu(A)=+\infty$ and $\mu(B)=-\infty$ then it doesn't make sense to even write $\mu(A) + \mu(B)$.  By requiring the measure to be finite-valued the issue doesn't arise.

You can also avoid this issue by considering measures that may either take the value $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ but not both.  But it is still not too satisfactory, as the set of such measures does not form a vector space.

Comment: While this is true, $|\mu|$ is a *positive* measure which may apriori (by its characterization) take on the value $+\infty$.  It is non-trivial to show that when $\mu$ is finite-valued, the *positive* measure $|\mu|$ is also finite.  The proof can be found in Rudin's book as I mentioned above.