# Lebesgue measure is not in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a follow-up question of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720552/is-mathcalm-mathbbrd-composed-of-finite-measures).

Let $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that vanish at infinity. By Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem, the dual of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ composed of all the real-valued regular Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. It is from the definition that for any $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$,

\begin{equation}
|\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)|\leq|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^d)=\|\mu\|_{\mathrm{TV}}<\infty.
\end{equation}

Now, we let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Since $m(\mathbb{R}^d)=\infty$, we have $m\notin\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. And in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, it is required that complex/real measure can not take $\infty$ value. So the Lebesgue measure is not complex/real measure.

Is my understanding correct? Thank you!

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is definitely not in the dual of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, yes. If you want to consider measures that can take infinite values, you need to instead consider the dual of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the space of compactly supported functions.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: The dual of $C_0(R)$ (real continuous functions vanishing at infinity) is the set of signed bounded measures, namely the differences of two positive bounded measures.

Comment: @DavidGao: $C_c(\Bbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $C_0(\Bbb{R}^d)$ in the $\sup$-norm.  There aren't any Banach spaces with elements whose norm is $\infty$.

Comment: @ChadK I should have clarified: I’m not talking about the dual of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as a normed space equipped with the sup norm. What I meant is more in line with the following: all positive linear functionals on $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (with no topology specified) are in one-to-one correspondence with all positive Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (with the possibility of taking infinite values).

Comment: @ChadK Though I’m pretty sure you can also choose a topology on $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to make something similar work, like regarding $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as the direct limit of the spaces of functions supported on increasing compact subsets (these latter spaces are all equipped with sup norm), then take the limit topology.